# Email уведомление об изменениях в Google Sheets

Tags: автоматизация, google-drive, google-docs-api, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Помогите реализовать такую вещь:

Если, допустим, в Google Sheets в ячейке `A1` появилось слово "Готово", то на емайл автоматически приходит письмо с содержанием какой-либо другой ячейки (допустим, `B2`).

Comment: @falconkolya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если вообще вне темы скриптов для Google Docs пока, загляните во [вводный курс](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) (на англ.).

[Документация по событиям](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) (на англ.) описывает триггер `onEdit()`, который срабатывает при любом изменении таблицы.

Вам нужно ловить только те, где поменялась искомая ячейка, и её значение. См. раздел "Spreadsheet Edit Events" — должен совпасть  `range`, и `value` должен присутствовать и иметь значение "Готово".

Для отправки письма используется класс [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app). Код выглядит примерно так:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(
    userEmail, 
    "Тема этого письма — ячейка готова!", 
    "Посмотрите документ - в нём ещё одна ячейка стала Готова:\n" +
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=xxxxxx\n\n" +
    message,               
    {name:"Иван Excel'евич Кукуев", cc:"kopiu_raz@mail.ru,kopiu_dva@mail.ru"}
);
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь. Я очень далек от программирования. Если не затруднит, объясните как все это сделать.

Comment: Посмотрите [эту страницу](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). 

Если сможете после этого сделать хотя бы какие-то шаги – шанс есть. Если нет, я бы порекомендовал искать исполнителя работы за оплату на фриланс сайтах.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать))

Answer (score 0):

google excel макросы поддерживает?

В модуле листа в процедуру

*Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)*

прописать обработку события изменения ячейки.

По событию - отсылка почты.

Приемы работы с почтой можно посмотреть в разделе "*[Интернет, почта](http://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/13/)*" на ресурсе, посвященному *Excel*